# Clear notations when working with random variables

Tags: notation

I have a set of random variables $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ each variable $X_i$ has a set of possible values $\Omega_{X_i}$ and a function associated with it $f(X_i)$. An assignment $\bf x$ for a subset of variables $\bf X$ is a mapping from each variable $X_i\in \bf X$ to its domain.

I am not a mathematician and more often I feel my notations are not expressive/clear to the reader of my work. For example, sometimes I use $X$ for both variable and set of variables.  Any suggestions on how to clearly describe them?

Comment: I think the answer depends on both context and convention.